# How to calculate the integral of an inverse function?

Tags: definite-integrals

If I have this function :$$\ f(x)=x^3+x $$ how can I calculate integral from inverse $$\int_0^1 f^{-1}(x)\,dx $$ ? I understand that in order do solve this problem I have to take $$\ x=f(t) $$ $$\ dx=f'(t) dt $$ and in the end I'll have $$\int t*f'(t)dt  $$ but I don't understand how I find the lower and upper bound of this integral without calculating the actual inverse of the function.

Comment: Integration limits are from $a=f^{-1}(0)$ to $b=f^{-1}(1)$, that is, the solutions to $f(a)=0$ and $f(b)=1$. The first one is easily $0$, the second one is [nasty](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E3%2Bx-1%3D0).

Comment: Thank you,I understand how to find the bounds now,the second solution is kind of weird but I doubt they wanted to write the integral like this in the book.I think they wanted to write from 0 to 2 since the last integral is from 0 to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put $t=f (x)$ or $x=g (t) $ where $g=f^{-1} $.

then
$$\int_0^1f (x)dx=\int_{f (0)}^{f (1)} tg'(t)dt $$

with

$$g'(t)=\frac {1}{f'(g (t))} $$

Comment: I got at this point but I don't know how to find the upper and lower bound of the integral,knowing that my first integral is from 0 to 1(forgot to put it first I edited it now)

Comment: @Lola is it okay now

Comment: Well in the book it says that the second integral is from 0 to 1 and I don't get those bounds if I calculate f(0) and f(1)

Answer (score 4):

There is a graphical proof of Young's inequality... the picture is:

[image]

And in case $b=f(a)$ you get a formula for one integral by subtracting the other from the area of a rectangle.

(When $b \ne f(a)$, the red area sticks out of the rectangle, which is where you get the "inequality" in the proof of Young's inequality.)